# openLDAP certificates untrusted or revoked

Tags: ssl, docker, openldap, replication, lets-encrypt

I've already spent two days on this problem but I can't find any solution.

Two `openLDAP` server run from docker on different hosts in master/master scenario. `ldapsearch` command or `syncrepl` process run perfectly with `ldap` protocol.
Now, I want to use a valid LE certificate to enable `ldaps` but I've got error : `TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x80002)` **but not from everywhere** !

#### Versions

Docker image is based on `debian:stable-slim` (v11.5 when I write theses lines).
Docker hosts are up to date Debian bullseye.
`slapd` version is `slapd 2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1`.

#### Config

`/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` file

```
TLS_CACERT  /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Here my relevant `slapd` config in `ldif` format :

```
dn: cn=config
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
olcArgsFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.args
olcIdleTimeout: 0
olcPidFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
olcSecurity: tls=0
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/key.pem
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/fullchain.pem
structuralObjectClass: olcGlobal
olcTLSProtocolMin: 3.1
olcServerId: 001 ldaps://ldap1.exemple.com
olcServerId: 002 ldaps://ldap2.exemple.com

# Load module
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module
olcModulePath: /usr/lib/ldap
olcModuleLoad: syncprov

dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcRootDN: cn=config
olcRootPW:: REDACTED
structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcSyncRepl: {0}rid=001 provider=ldaps://ldap1.exemple.com binddn="cn=config" bindmethod=simple credentials="REDACTED" searchbase="cn=config" filter="(objectClass=*)" scope="sub" attrs="*,+" schemachecking=off type=refreshAndPersist retry="5 5 300 5" timeout=1
olcSyncRepl: {1}rid=002 provider=ldaps://ldap2.exemple.com binddn="cn=config" bindmethod=simple credentials="REDACTED" searchbase="cn=config" filter="(objectClass=*)" scope="sub" attrs="*,+" schemachecking=off type=refreshAndPersist retry="5 5 300 5" timeout=1
olcMirrorMode: TRUE
```

#### Tests

From docker host to `openLDAP` guest :
From MacOS host to `openLDAP` guest :
From one `openLDAP` guest to self :
From one `openLDAP` guest to other `openLDAP` guest :

```bash
$ openssl s_client -connect ldap1.exemple.com:636
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = ldap1.exemple.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = ldap1.exemple.com
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   i:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
 2 s:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 5112 bytes and written 392 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

So, certificat seems valid in any ways.

==========

From docker host to `openLDAP` guest :
From one `openLDAP` guest to self :
From one `openLDAP` guest to other `openLDAP` guest :

```bash
$ ldapsearch -x -LLL -d 1  -H ldaps://ldap1.exemple.com -D cn=config -W -b cn=config cn=config
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://ldap1.exemple.com)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://ldap1.exemple.com:636/??base)
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP ldap1.exemple.com:636
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.65.2:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x80002)
TLS: can't connect: (unknown error code).
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

From MacOS host to `openLDAP` guest with built-in `ldapsearch` command :
From MacOS host to `openLDAP` guest with `homebrew` `ldapsearch` command :

```bash
$ ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldaps://ldap1.exemple.com -D cn=config -w REDACTED -b cn=config cn=config
dn: cn=config
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
olcArgsFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.args
olcIdleTimeout: 0
olcPidFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
olcSecurity: tls=0
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/key.pem
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/fullchain.pem
structuralObjectClass: olcGlobal
olcTLSProtocolMin: 3.1
olcServerId: 001 ldaps://ldap1.exemple.com
olcServerId: 002 ldaps://ldap2.exemple.com
```

Here, certificat is only trusted from MacOS host and I don't know why.
The same behavior happen is I replace `olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` by `olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/fullchain.pem` in `slapd` config.

I need that docker hosts and `openLDAP` guests recognize LE certificates to allow `ldap*` commands and `syncrepl` process works with `ldaps` protocols.

I know that I can add `TLS_REQCERT allow` in `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` file. But it works only with `ldap*` command and not `syncrepl` process.

What did I miss ? What I'm doing wrong ?

PS: I edit DNS entry to ldap1.exemple.com but I use a real DNS entry an valid LE certificats (no staging ones)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally find why certificates are considered `untrusted or revoked`.

My certificates are generated with Apache HTTPD module `mod_md` with `MDMustStaple` directive to `On`.

OpenLDAP do not handle `OCSP Stapling`.

I made a request to LE for new certificates without OCSP must stapling flag and now everything work perfectly, `ldap*` commands or `syncrepl` process.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the package `libldap-common`. It was not automatically installed as a dependency of `ldap-utils` in our environment. After installing the package, the error went away, and we were able to connect to an LDAP server, which uses a LetsEncrypt certificate.

If you're facing the following error, you've to install `libsasl2-modules`, too:

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Unknown authentication method (-6)
    additional info: SASL(-4): no mechanism available: No worthy mechs found
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding `TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x80002)` is to decode the number. The error message is produced by OpenLDAP but the numeric error code is from GnuTLS.

https://codesearch.debian.net reveals that this error message is printed only at https://sources.debian.org/src/openldap/2.5.13+dfsg-5/libraries/libldap/tls_g.c/?hl=1195#L1195, which reveals that the number is stored by `gnutls_certificate_verify_peers2()`, whose [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/gnutls-doc/gnutls_certificate_verify_peers2.3.en.html) says: "This function will verify the peer's certificate and store the status in the status variable as a bitwise OR of gnutls_certificate_status_t values or zero if the certificate is trusted."

The values of gnutls_certificate_status_t are defined in [gnutls.h.in](https://github.com/gnutls/gnutls/blob/master/lib/includes/gnutls/gnutls.h.in#:%7E:text=%7D%20gnutls_certificate_status_t;). Current list:

```c
typedef enum {
    GNUTLS_CERT_INVALID = 1 << 1,                           //      0x2
    GNUTLS_CERT_REVOKED = 1 << 5,                           //     0x20
    GNUTLS_CERT_SIGNER_NOT_FOUND = 1 << 6,                  //     0x40
    GNUTLS_CERT_SIGNER_NOT_CA = 1 << 7,                     //     0x80
    GNUTLS_CERT_INSECURE_ALGORITHM = 1 << 8,                //    0x100
    GNUTLS_CERT_NOT_ACTIVATED = 1 << 9,                     //    0x200
    GNUTLS_CERT_EXPIRED = 1 << 10,                          //    0x400
    GNUTLS_CERT_SIGNATURE_FAILURE = 1 << 11,                //    0x800
    GNUTLS_CERT_REVOCATION_DATA_SUPERSEDED = 1 << 12,       //   0x1000
    GNUTLS_CERT_UNEXPECTED_OWNER = 1 << 14,                 //   0x4000
    GNUTLS_CERT_REVOCATION_DATA_ISSUED_IN_FUTURE = 1 << 15, //   0x8000
    GNUTLS_CERT_SIGNER_CONSTRAINTS_FAILURE = 1 << 16,       //  0x10000
    GNUTLS_CERT_MISMATCH = 1 << 17,                         //  0x20000
    GNUTLS_CERT_PURPOSE_MISMATCH = 1 << 18,                 //  0x40000
    GNUTLS_CERT_MISSING_OCSP_STATUS = 1 << 19,              //  0x80000
    GNUTLS_CERT_INVALID_OCSP_STATUS = 1 << 20,              // 0x100000
    GNUTLS_CERT_UNKNOWN_CRIT_EXTENSIONS = 1 << 21           // 0x200000
} gnutls_certificate_status_t;
```

For example, `0x80002` is GNUTLS_CERT_MISSING_OCSP_STATUS + GNUTLS_CERT_INVALID. So it directly points to an OCSP related problem. It's a shame the error message is so terrible.

---

In my case the error was `TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x42)` which equals GNUTLS_CERT_SIGNER_NOT_FOUND + GNUTLS_CERT_INVALID. That's still not very useful.

GnuTLS has a command line tool [`gnutls-cli`](https://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/gnutls_002dcli-Invocation.html) which can show more details. It is similar to OpenSSL's `openssl s_client` but it's best to use the right tool because they don't always behave the same. On Debian it's installed with `apt install gnutls-bin`.

```bash
# Connect to LDAPS:
$ gnutls-cli ldap.example.com:636

# Connect to LDAP with STARTTLS:
$ gnutls-cli --starttls-proto=ldap ldap.example.com:389
```

---

In my particular case the problem was that our LDAP server was misconfigured and it was sending the leaf certificate twice in the chain. OpenSSL is okay with that but GnuTLS rejects it. The fix was to use `.../chain.pem` instead of `.../fullchain.pem` in the LDAP server config. To find the root cause it was very helpful to compare the gnutls-cli output between the bad LDAP server and a working HTTPS server with the same cert. I don't know if anyone else will have this exact problem, but at least it's a good example of how gnutls-cli can help.

```
$ gnutls-cli --starttls-proto=ldap example.com:389
Processed 137 CA certificate(s).
Resolving 'example.com:389'...
Connecting to '[...]:389'...
- Certificate type: X.509
- Got a certificate list of 4 certificates.
- Certificate[0] info:
 - subject `CN=*.example.com', issuer `CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US', serial [...], EC/ECDSA key 256 bits, signed using RSA-SHA256, activated `2023-11-24 xx:xx:xx UTC', expires `2024-02-22 xx:xx:xx UTC', pin-sha256="[...]"
- Certificate[1] info:
 - subject `CN=*.example.com', issuer `CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US', serial [...], EC/ECDSA key 256 bits, signed using RSA-SHA256, activated `2023-11-24 xx:xx:xx UTC', expires `2024-02-22 xx:xx:xx UTC', pin-sha256="[...]"
- Certificate[2] info:
 - subject `CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US', issuer `CN=ISRG Root X1,O=Internet Security Research Group,C=US', serial 0x00912b084acf0c18a753f6d62e25a75f5a, RSA key 2048 bits, signed using RSA-SHA256, activated `2020-09-04 00:00:00 UTC', expires `2025-09-15 16:00:00 UTC', pin-sha256="jQJTbIh0grw0/1TkHSumWb+Fs0Ggogr621gT3PvPKG0="
- Certificate[3] info:
 - subject `CN=ISRG Root X1,O=Internet Security Research Group,C=US', issuer `CN=DST Root CA X3,O=Digital Signature Trust Co.', serial 0x4001772137d4e942b8ee76aa3c640ab7, RSA key 4096 bits, signed using RSA-SHA256, activated `2021-01-20 19:14:03 UTC', expires `2024-09-30 18:14:03 UTC', pin-sha256="C5+lpZ7tcVwmwQIMcRtPbsQtWLABXhQzejna0wHFr8M="
- Status: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.
*** PKI verification of server certificate failed...
*** Fatal error: Error in the certificate.
```

---

Finally, note that gnutls-cli automatically loads the operating system's Certificate Authorities, but ldapsearch only loads them if properly configured.

This is the reason why [ForJ9's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1136224/1064310) recommends installing `libldap-common`. It is a Debian package containing only a single file `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` (and some docs) which contains only a single uncommented line:

```
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

For robustness, you can set this option directly on the ldapsearch command line, like this:

```
ldapsearch -v -d 65535 -ZZ -H ldap://example.com:389/ -o tls_cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -x '(objectClass=*)'
```